# Need help with this proof using inverse limits

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

I'm reading a paper that involves inverse limits. I'm not familiar with them, and need some help deciphering this construction.

> Proof. Let $ X $ be a compact space of weight at most $ \aleph _ 1 $. Since the Tychonoff cube $ I ^ { \aleph _ 1 } $ is a continuous image of the Cantor cube $ D ^ { \aleph _ 1 } $, we can assume $ X $ to be a closed subspace of $ D ^ { \aleph _ 1 } $. We shall consider $ D ^ { \aleph _ 1 } $ as the limit of the inverse system $$ D \longleftarrow D ^ 2 \longleftarrow \cdots \longleftarrow D ^ \alpha \overset { p _ \alpha ^ { \alpha + 1 } } \longleftarrow D ^ { \alpha + 1 } \longleftarrow \cdots \overset { p _ \beta } \longleftarrow D ^ { \aleph _ 1 } \text , $$ where $ D = \{ 0 , 1 \} $, $ D ^ { \alpha + 1 } = D ^ \alpha \times D $, $ D ^ \beta = \underset \leftarrow \lim \, \{ D ^ \alpha , p _ \alpha ^ { \alpha + 1 } , \alpha < \beta \} $ for limit $ \beta $ and $ p _ \alpha ^ { \alpha + 1 } $ are projections, i.e. $ p _ \alpha ^ { \alpha + 1 } ( x ) = x | \alpha $ for $ \alpha < \aleph _ 1 $.  Since $ X \subset D ^ { \aleph _ 1 } $, $ X = \underset { \leftarrow } \lim \, \{ X _ \alpha , q _ \alpha ^ { \alpha + 1 } , \alpha < \aleph _ 1 \} $, where $ X _ \alpha = p _ \alpha ( X ) $, $ q _ \alpha ^ { \alpha + 1 } = p _ \alpha ^ { \alpha + 1 } | X _ { \alpha + 1 } $, $ \alpha < \aleph _ 1 $. [Screenshot of source at https://i.stack.imgur.com/55BXH.png]

I understand $D^{\beta}$ is a subset of $p_{\alpha<\beta}D^{\alpha}$, where each $x_{\alpha}$ is such that $p_{\alpha}^{\alpha+1}(x_{\alpha+1})=x_{\alpha}$. I don't understand how $p_{\beta}$ acts though. What does it map to?

I understand the Cantor cube is just a product of continuum many $D$. It says this is the inverse limit though, and that's generally a subset of the product, not the entire product space? Is the Cantor cube the entire product space, or an inverse limit or both?

Also, since $X$ is subspace of the Cantor cube, you can write it as an inverse limit as well? Is this a general result, is $X$ is a subset of an inverse limit, it can be written as an inverse limit as well?

Comment: It's better to type out references than to show an image.  I realize that this might be a daunting task in this case, so I've done it for you; but you should check my work for typos.  (I did change one thing, which appears to be a typo in the original: there was a missing close brace in the inverse limit on the last line of the text.)

Comment: PS: I do also intend to write an answer, but I suddenly have to go for a couple of hours.